# Basic GUI window not appearing

Tags: java, swing

Doing a basic two panel code panel is to give the information and provide a box to input data, and the second simply to quit or execute. Initially, the blank window would appear, but after adding panelTwo and the window no longer appears.

The program compiles and shows no errors, except in the main class it tells me "New instance ignored" pertaining to new SalesClassGUI ();. Unsure how to procede any help would be appreciated!

```
public class SalesClassGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panelOne;
    private JPanel panelTwo;

    private JLabel associateNameLabel;
    private JLabel associateNumberLabel;
    private JLabel productSoldLabel;
    private JLabel productPriceLabel;
    private JLabel stateCodeLabel;
    private JLabel regionCodeLabel;
    private JLabel productNumberLabel;
    private JLabel productDescripLabel;

    private JTextField associateNameField;
    private JTextField associateNumberField;
    private JTextField productSoldField;
    private JTextField productPriceField;
    private JTextField stateCodeField;
    private JTextField regionCodeField;
    private JTextField productNumberField;
    private JTextField productDescripField;

    private JButton calcButton;
    private JButton exitButton;

    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

    public void SalesClassGUI() {

        setTitle("Associate Tracker");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout (new GridLayout (8,1)); 
        buildPanel();
        add(panelOne);
        add(panelTwo);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildPanel() {

        associateNameLabel = new JLabel("Enter name of associate");
        associateNumberLabel = new JLabel("Enter associate number");
        productSoldLabel = new JLabel("Enter number of product sold");
        productPriceLabel = new JLabel("Enter price of the product");
        stateCodeLabel = new JLabel("Enter state code");
        regionCodeLabel = new JLabel("Enter region code");
        productNumberLabel = new JLabel("Enter product number");
        productDescripLabel = new JLabel("Enter product description");

        associateNameField = new JTextField();
        associateNumberField = new JTextField();
        productSoldField = new JTextField();
        productPriceField = new JTextField();
        stateCodeField = new JTextField();
        regionCodeField = new JTextField();
        productNumberField = new JTextField();
        productDescripField = new JTextField();

        //associate name
        panelOne = new JPanel();
        /*panelOne.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 2));*/


        panelOne.add(associateNameLabel);
        panelOne.add(associateNameField);

        //associate number
        panelOne.add(associateNumberLabel);
        panelOne.add(associateNumberField);

        //prouct sold
        panelOne.add(productSoldLabel);
        panelOne.add(productSoldField);

        //product price
        panelOne.add(productPriceLabel);
        panelOne.add(productPriceField);

        //state code
        panelOne = new JPanel();
        panelOne.add(stateCodeLabel);
        panelOne.add(stateCodeField);

        //region code
        panelOne.add(regionCodeLabel);
        panelOne.add(regionCodeField);

        //product number
        panelOne.add(productNumberLabel);
        panelOne.add(productNumberField);

        //product description
        panelOne.add(productDescripLabel);
        panelOne.add(productDescripField);

        panelTwo = new JPanel();

        panelTwo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        // Define the button
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

        // Add the buttons to the panel
        panelTwo.add(calcButton);
        panelTwo.add(exitButton);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalesClassGUI salesClassGUI = new SalesClassGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you really should be executing the GUI code on the Event Dispatch thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has no constructor.  So when you call `new SalesClassGUI()`, the default constructor is invoked, which does nothing.  And then your program just terminates.

To properly declare a constructor, you need to omit the return type.

Change:

```
public void SalesClassGUI() {
```

to:

```
public SalesClassGUI() {
```

Note: you're going to get an NPE because your ctor has some bugs, but this will remove the "nothing happens" problem.  I found this by stepping through the code in a debugger.  You should learn to do that as well.

Also, another good debugging technique is just to add some print statements to track the flow of the program, and to verify that the code is reaching certain points.  This is what tipped me off that that the something was seriously off and I needed to use the debugger.

```
public SalesClassGUI() {
    setTitle("Associate Tracker");
    System.err.println( "ctor" );
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout (new GridLayout (8,1)); 
    buildPanel();
    add(panelOne);
    add(panelTwo);
    pack();
    System.err.println( "setvisible true" );
    setVisible(true);
}
```

When "ctor" didn't print I knew something was really wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this helped alot! I ran into issues when removing the void, but essentially just incorporated the buildPanel() method in with the SalesClass and everything worked! Thanks a lot!